# Fill spinner from cursor in android

Tags: android

i have searched for a awnser for this for a while today. It all looks so easy but i never get it to work. I want to fill a spinner with my cursor. I have been trying to use SimpleCursorAdapter for this as a lot of sites say i shall but i never get it to work. Show me just how easy it is :)

Thanks for your time!

My cursor

```
Cursor cursor = db.query(DATABASE_TABLE_Clients, new String[] {"_id", "C_Name"}, null, null, null, null, "C_Name");
```

My spinner

```
(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spnClients);
```

My Code

```
Cursor cursor_Names = SQLData.getClientNames();
startManagingCursor(cursor_Names);

String[] columns = new String[] { "C_Name" };
int[] to = new int[] { R.id.txt_Address };

SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, cursor_Names, columns, to);
Spinner spnClients = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spnClients);
spnClients.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Comment: Can you show us the complete code, especially your use of the SimpleCursorAdapter?

Comment: Added the code. How to use columns and to is something i don't understand to. I have tested with alot of diffrent values there but it only makes a empty spinner with radio buttons in it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following code solved my problem. I was missing **.setDropDownViewResource**. After that i used **simple_spinner_dropdown_item** so i don't have to make my own layout.

```
    Cursor cursor_Names = SQLData.getClientNames();
    startManagingCursor(cursor_Names);

    String[] columns = new String[] { "C_Name" };
    int[] to = new int[] { android.R.id.text1 };

    SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, cursor_Names, columns, to);
    mAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    Spinner spnClients = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spnClients);
    spnClients.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Answer (score 5):

I don't see a View for your dropdown in your code. Something like:

```
mAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_view_dropdown);
```

Of course you need to have a spinner_view_dropdown.xml file in your res/layout directory.

Answer (score 0):

I have done it

```
    empresasSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.empresasSpinner);

  ArrayAdapter spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, empresasAll.toArray(new EntidadObject[0]));                
            empresasSpinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
```

A simple DTO

```
public class EntidadObject {
    private int id;
    private String nombre;
//GETTES and SETTERS
}
```

The part DAO

```
public class EntidadDao {
             //...

        public List<EntidadObject> getEmpresas() {
                Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM empresas", null);
                List<EntidadObject> entidadObjects = new ArrayList<EntidadObject>();
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                do {
                    EntidadObject entidadObject = new EntidadObject();
                    entidadObject.setId(cursor.getInt(0));
                    entidadObject.setNombre(cursor.getString(1));

                    entidadObjects.add(entidadObject);
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
                return entidadObjects;
            }
   }
```

So then I can catch the ID of the select item with

```
EntidadObject eo = (EntidadObject)empresasSpinner.getSelectedItem();
              eo.getId();
```